# Blender won't load UI text when opened from the console on a Mac

Tags: command-line, osx

To open multiple instances of Blender on a Mac, I'm opening blender.app (2.75a and 2.75) through the console. That makes Blender's interface load with most of the text gone:
 [image: loadBug]

Vs. the normal way of opening Blender with Finder:
[image: Normal startup]

I tried:

```
open -n .../blender.app
open -n .../blender.app/contents/MacOS/blender
```

I also tried only `./` and tried to open the app manually inside the package contents, all with the same result. I also tried with 2.74, and the same happens. Oddly enough I am looking at a tutorial in which the guy has 2 instances opened on a Mac without much problem.

So, what's going on? If I have to make 2 instances of blender.app, it's ok, but how can I get the console window method to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had two versions of python installed; I solved this by uninstalling the 2.7 version by typing:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
```

and then:

```
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"
```

That leaves me with 3.4, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded Blender 2.75a on my mac with OSX 10.10.3 (Yosemite). Placed on my desktop, I open the terminal and executed this line:

```
/Users/[myusername]/Desktop/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender
```

Blender loaded properly with all menus intact. No "open" command is required. I can do multiple instances this way.

Comment: Ill try that way, wait a sec

Comment: after typing :  /Users/(-U-N-)/Desktop/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender; blender opens, but still I will get the very same issue that the screenshot shows, also I noticed this message in the console: .../Desktop/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender
ndof: 3Dx driver not found
Read new prefs: /Users/Kaahrl/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.75/config/userpref.blend
2015-07-31 17:35:10.164 blender[31188:7772658] 17:35:10.164 WARNING:
blablabla

Comment: as a matter of fact I 99% sure that is something about my mac configuration since I saw this work to everybody....

Comment: and yeah Yosemite here too... maybe something about permissions/ priviledges etc...? is like if it couldn't read part of the program

Comment: oh, I think myght be something about my python config since at the end of the console you can read: 
uiItemStringO: 'WM_OT_url_open' unknown operator
python line lookup failed, interpreter inactive
search for unknown menutype USERPREF_MT_splash_footer